# satisfy a shift model

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference

Positive random variables  and  satisfy a scale model with parameters >0, if (≤)=(≤) for all >0, or equivalently, ()=(/),  > 0, >0.

To Prove:

log  and log  satisfy a shift model with parameter log .

Do I replace  with log or start with a log Y + log ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow the definition: you should prove that $\log X$ and $\log Y$ satisfy a shift model with parameter $\log \delta$, that is 
$$\tag{1}\label{1}
\mathbb P(\log Y\leq t) = \mathbb P(\log \delta + \log X\leq t)
$$ 
Left-hand side is equal to
$$
\mathbb P(\log Y\leq t) = \mathbb P(Y \leq e^t)
$$
R.h.s. is 
$$
\mathbb P(\log \delta + \log X\leq t) = \mathbb P(\log (\delta X)\leq t) = \mathbb P(\delta X\leq e^t).
$$ 
You are given that 
$$
\mathbb P(Y \leq e^t) = \mathbb P(\delta X\leq e^t),
$$
so \eqref{1} is proved.